# SAS summary data transposed to line list?

Tags: count, sas, transpose

I have a data set like this

```
YEAR GENDER RACE AGE COUNT
2015  Female W   30    3
```

So in 2015, there were 3 White 30 year females.  I'd like to transpose this into line list data, like this:

```
YEAR GENDER RACE AGE 
2015 Female W    30
2015 Female W    30
2015 Female W    30
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I added a row for purpose of illustration:

```
data have;
    input YEAR GENDER $ RACE $ AGE COUNT;
    datalines;
    2015 Female W 30 3
    2014 Male B 45 4
;
```

The following code will hopefully accomplish what you are asking for:

```
data want (drop=i count);
    set have;

    do i = 1 to count;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: That does work when I copy it exactly- is there a way to modify the do loop to work when I already have a data set that I've imported from excel?

Comment: You shouldn't have to change anything in the do loop. Have you modified the "set have" statement to the name of your imported dataset?

Comment: I've got this: 
data want (drop=i count); 
set narcan; 
do i=1 to count; 
output;
end; 
run;  
(narcan is my imported dataset), and I'm getting this error message- "invalid do loop control information, either the initial or to expression is missing or the by expression is missing, zero, or invalid"

Comment: Are there any missing values or values less than 1 in "count"?

Comment: There were, and when I got rid of them, your code worked like a charm.  Thanks very much!!